# Simple euler's identity question

Tags: power

In the equation below when I evaluate it I get the imaginary part as positive. But in the book it is given as negative?

what am I doing wrong?

[image: Space vector equation]

Comment: As long as you don't tell how \$f_\alpha\$ and \$f_\beta\$ are defined this question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have read it right? If you did, I think the book may be wrong...

The only alternate form I can think of that would look similar (not really...) is:

$$|{F}|e^{j\theta_0}e^{j\omega t} = \sqrt{F^2}\cos(\theta_0+\omega t) + j\sqrt{F^2}\sin(\theta_0+\omega t)\\
=F \cos(\theta_0+\omega t)+\sqrt{-(F)^2}\sin(\theta_0+\omega t)$$

This might be better off posted in the maths section...

Comment: thanks a lot. Your conformation makes me sure that it has to be a misprint in the book.

Comment: i don't think the square roots and squares do anything to elucidate.

Comment: .... and BTW \$\sqrt{-F^2}=\pm \text{j}\,F\$ so what were you really after?

Answer (score 0):

\$e^{j\theta}e^{j\omega t}=\cos(\omega t)(\cos\: \theta+j\sin\:\theta) -j\sin(\omega t)(\cos\: \theta+j\sin\:\theta)\$

Comment: I'm not sure were the minus comes into it